# Is there an easy way to remove all default values for a SQL database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I'd like to remove all default values that have been setup in a particular database, is there a script that I can run to do this for all tables in database? Could be a bit time consuming without ... any help would be appreciated!

Comment: @CodeByMoonlight Good point ... SQL Server 2005 and 2008.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're on SQL Server 2005 and up, you could use this script to create another script which will then drop all your default constraints:

```
SELECT 
    'ALTER TABLE dbo.' + OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) + 
    ' DROP CONSTRAINT ' + Name
FROM
    sys.default_constraints
```

This will create as output a series of statements such as

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable DROP CONSTRAINT DF_T_YourColumn
```

Copy the output into another SQL Server Management Studio query window and execute it and you should be done!

Marc

Answer (score 3):

You could generate a script to drop all default constraints:

```
SELECT 'alter table ' + object_name(parent_object_id) + 
    ' drop constraint ' + name
FROM sys.objects
WHERE type = 'D'
```

Comment: I would recommend using the more targeted "sys.default_constraints" instead of always relying on "sys.objects" and having to figure out what type it is I'm about to deal with....